# What is the meaning of word "alibi"

Tags: meaning

I know the basic meaning of the word "alibi". It is a form of criminal defence which claims the accused was somewhere else when a specific crime happened. It also has a meaning of "excuse, defence".

However, I noticed the titles of several songs like "Love is my alibi", "Music is my alibi" or "He is my alibi". What does they mean? "Love is my excuse" or "Music is my excuse" ?

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: It's a metaphor for 'excuse'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Alibi](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=alibi)*** meaning "excuse" had been used since the beginning of the 20th century by extension of the original meaning:

> - 1743, "the plea of having been elsewhere when an action took place," from Latin alibi "elsewhere, somewhere else," locative of alius "(an)other" (see alias (adv.)). ***The weakened sense of "excuse" is attested since 1912, but technically any proof of innocence that doesn't involve being "elsewhere" is an excuse, not an alibi.***

(Etymonline)

Comment: Josh61, what does it mean "Love is my alibi" ?

Comment: The literal meaning is "love is my excuse", but you need context. It may be your excuse for misbehaving or for doing something out of the ordinary just because you do it in the name of love.